# How can i access session in different jspx?

Tags: http, jsp, session, jspx

I'm new to jspx and I'm not sure how I would do this. I have created a model-view-controller and have created a session in controller. Once the user has logged in, it creates the session.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("user", username);
```

How can I access and display the username in the welcome.jspx page, so it would say

```
hello username
```

Comment: Please edit your question. You have written "I'm new to jsp " thats why I wrote syntax for JSP page. But you wanted for JSPX.

Comment: @GP: OP explicitly mentioned JSPX in title, tags and even file extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) to access it.

```
hello ${user}
```

To prevent XSS attacks by username, show it using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:out>` so that XML special characters are escaped:

```html
<jsp:root xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" ...>
...

hello <c:out value="${user}" />
```

Comment: I have tried this and it does say hello but there's nothing afterwards. Does that mean that it has not set the session

Comment: You need to ensure that the controller is invoked before the JSP within the same session.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this (For JSP):

```
<%
  String username = (String)session.getAttribute("user");
  out.println("<b>Welcome " + username + "!</b>");
%>
```

I have used scriptlet tag here. You can study about it  [from here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html) .

(may be it could help someone else.)

Comment: Scriptlets are not allowed in JSPX this way.

Comment: It just comes up as text when i run it

Comment: well, you are making jspx page thats why. I thought it is simply jsp.

Comment: Regardless, scriptlets are strongly discouraged since a decade.